# Sendmail Relay Issue

Tags: centos, smtp, sendmail, centos7, relay

I have installed sendmail on Centos 7 and setup relay server using SMART_HOST.
But sendmail is not using my relay server when sending email, it keeps using localhost.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail-8.12+ by default relays messages submitted locally to local main sendmail daemon running at 127.0.0.1:25.  It does it as a security precaution to avoid installation as set root uid.

Have you checked sendmail log files?  They should show where main local sendmail daemon relays messages to non local email addresses.

Documentation: [**SECURITY** file in sendmail distribution](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/security/secure-install/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Here's my log.
Feb 13 14:02:48 myhostname sendmail[13452]: v1D62m88013452: to=apache, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31112, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v1D62mdX013453 Message accepted for delivery)
Can you guide me further, please?

Comment: 1) There should be **FOUR** (4) log entries. Pairs of `from=` and `to=` log entries by MSA and MTA. 2) `to=apache` suggests local mailbox as the destination.  SMART_HOST is not involved in deliveries to local mailboxes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, again.
Do you have any idea why SMART_HOST is not involved?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.
The mistake was with LOCAL_DOMAIN.
I had put my local domain (which was used for mail server and email address) here.
And all of my emails were being handled as local emails.
Local emails were meant for excluding from relay, lol.